# How do I allow for fallback to a Apple Maps if Google Maps isn't installed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, xamarin.ios, apple-maps

I have a tab controller that will show nearby stores.  I know that 40% of my users have never (or can't though policy) install Google Maps.

How can I fall back to Apple maps if Google Maps isn't installed?

To make things just a little more complex, the "nearby stores" is a tab in a tabbed application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, the only way you're displaying a Google Map inside your app is by including Google's library -- thereby making moot the question of "is Google Maps installed here".

If you are speaking in terms of *opening* the Google Maps app if it exists and falling back to the Apple Maps app, you'd use `UIApplication`'s [`-canOpenURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:) method, passing in the scheme for Google's Maps app, which is `comgooglemaps://`.

Good luck!